# How to find confidence Yolo V8

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

I trained a model to detect traffic lights and classify thier color, `[red,green,yellow,off]`.

I want to only display the lights with a confidence above 50%, but I cant figure out how to do that with yolo v8. Ive tried using `.conf` and `.prob` as the documentation states but its all empty. Here is my current script. It streams webcam view and looks for stoplights.

Any help to get confidence values or even just the classification values from this would be amazing. I have uploaded the [model to github here](https://github.com/Syazvinski/Traffic-Light-Detection-Color-Classification) for people that want to test.

I reccomend using the `best_traffic_nano_yolo.pt` model as its the most lightweight.

Googling `traffic light at intersection` and holding an your phone up to the webcam should be enough for the model to detect and classify the light.

```py
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a pretrained YOLOv8n model
model = YOLO('/Models/best_traffic_nano_yolo.pt')

# open a video file or start a video stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # replace with 0 for webcam

while cap.isOpened():
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # flip the image
    # frame = cv2.flip(frame, -1) 

    # Run inference on the current frame
    results = model(frame)  # results list

    for r in results:
        frame = r.plot()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    
    # Press 'q' on keyboard to  exit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# After the loop release the cap object and destroy all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: if you notice: the `for r in results:` loop body will cause you to only see the ***last result***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the overall confidence threshold value for the prediction process:

```
results = model(frame, conf=0.5)
```

To get the confidence and class values from the prediction results (in case you are working with the detection task model which predicts **boxes**):

```
results[0].boxes.conf
results[0].boxes.cls
```

Index [0] stands for the first predicted image, as you pass only one image at a time, you need only [0] values of the results.

*prob* value is for the classification task model, it contains probabilities of each class, and it will be empty for object detection task results. More about working with the prediction results: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#working-with-results